# How to mock a void method with Functional Interface in a dao method?

Tags: java, mocking, functional-interface

I would like to  mock a void method  with Functional Interface in a dao method. Somehow I couldn't adopt the examples.
The code is (more or less) as the following:

```
...
public interface StreamNode {
    void nodeInit    (StreamRecord record);
    void nodeProcess (StreamRecord record);
    void nodeControl (StreamRecord record);
    void nodeCommit  (StreamRecord record);
    void nodeRollback(StreamRecord record);
}
private final JdbcDao processDao;
...
processDao.downloadSplittedStreamRecords (sqlStatement2,
                                                  paramMap,
                                                  instNum,
                                                  templateRecord,
                                                  consumerScale,
                                                 "SOLUTION",       
                                                  tempSolutionsSet,            
                                                  colToRecNameMap,              
                                                  new StreamRecordForwarder() { // Functional interface object
                                                      public void forwardRecord(StreamRecord record) {

                                                          record.putS(Fields.YEAR_S,              record.getS(Fields.SELECTABLEYEARMONTH_S).substring(0,4));
                                                          record.putS(Fields.TTCLOSEDYEARMONTH_S, record.getS(Fields.SELECTABLEYEARMONTH_S));
                                                          nextNode.nodeProcess(record);
                                                      }
        });
```

```
Test Code
 @Mock
        EttsYearlyAggregatorNode ettsYearlyAggregatorNode;
...
   Mockito.doNothing().when(processDao).downloadSplittedStreamRecords(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),....);

...
 verify(ettsYearlyAggregatorNode,times(1)).nodeProcess( refEq(expectedRecord,"recordNum"));
```

Comment: show us the test code you have written so far

Comment: Mockito.doNothing().when(processDao).downloadRecords(eq("select * from   SLA_SOLUTION"),
                                                                      eq(paramMap),                                                                      
                                                                      any(StreamRecordForwarder.class));

Comment: so what is happening ? Are u getting an error?

Comment: nodeProcess(record) will not be invoked.

Comment: verify(node,times(1)).nodeProcess( refEq(expectedRecord,"recordNum")); this fails

Comment: please edit the question and put the test code that you have written so far

Comment: is `nodeProcess` an internal method in the same class?

Comment: nodeProcess is a method in the node class

Comment: And where is this Node class? if you want people to help, you should put as much information as possible.   You should put all the code which are relevant and also your test code.  It is not possible to assume everything and give you solution. Good luck.

Comment: please try `...downloadRecords(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), any(),...)` ..i fear the `eq(paramMap)` does not match!

Comment: or `..., any(java.util.Map.class), any(...))` accordingly

Comment: ok thanks i will try it

Comment: unfortunatelly the result is the same nodeProcess() method was not invoked.